# How can I call multiple beans that all implement a specific interface?

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel

I have a set of beans that implement an interface. I want to multicast an incoming message to an explicit (sub)set of these beans using a method from this interface. The method call will result in a `List<Object>` for each bean. I want to aggregate all the lists into one big list and pass that on to the next route.

My first approach was to create a route for each bean that passes the result to the aggregation route. However I think I lose the type-safety that I tried to enforce with the interface. (In other words, I cannot prevent other people from adding beans to the multicast that do not implement the interface. I believe this could lead to an error in my aggregation strategy at runtime (e.g. body is not a list).)

The Interface:

```
public interface Reporter {
    List<Object> report();
}
```

An example of the routes I created for each bean that implements the interface:

```
<route>
    <from uri="direct:bean1"/>
    <bean ref="reporterOfSomething" method="report"/>
    <to uri="seda:aggregate"/>
</route>
```

My current approach is to create a list bean with a value-type attribute referencing the Reporter interface and adding the implementing beans to this list. This way I have my types checked by the scheme validation, not just when the route is called. However I couldn't figure out how to multicast the incoming message to each bean in the list.

```
<util:list id="reporters" value-type="Reporter"><!-- i.e. the interface -->
    <ref bean="reporterOfSomething"/>
    <ref bean="reporterOfSomethingElse"/>
</util:list>
```

So I have the feeling that I'm either overcomplicating things or just not using the right constructs.

How can I call all these beans and have some form of type-safety (e.g. Intellij complains that I violate the scheme when I pass a bean of the wrong type or the application could crash during startup or some other way that will cause a compile/scheme/initialization error)?

Comment: routingslip or recipientlist maybe ?

Comment: @Sikorski A recipient list would result in the multicast I describe under My first approach. The routing slip seems to result into a similar construction, but not as explicit as the recipient list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a processor that iterates over the reporting beans and aggregates the results of the single reporter beans:

```
public class ReporterProcessor implements Processor {
    private List<Reporter> reporters;
    @Override
    public void process(final Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        List<Object> aggregatedList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (final ReporterBean reporter : reporters) {
            aggregatedList.add(reporter.report(exchange));
        }
        exchange.getIn().setBody(aggregatedList);
    }
    public void setReporters(final List<Reporter> reporters) {
        this.reporters = reporters;
    }
}
```

Camel route definition:

```
<util:list id="reporterList" value-type="Reporter"> <!-- i.e. the interface -->
    <ref bean="reporterOfSomething"/>
    <ref bean="reporterOfSomethingElse"/>
</util:list>

<bean id="reporterProcessor" class="ReporterProcessor">
    <property name="reporters" ref="reporterList" />
</bean>

<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <route>
        <from uri="direct:bean1"/>
        <process ref="reporterProcessor"/>
        <to uri="seda:aggregate"/>
    </route>
</camelContext>
```

That way, all the results of the single reporter beans are aggregated and passed to `seda:aggregate`.

Comment: This is a possible solution. Actually, with this implementation I don't think I would need the aggregation anymore, since the processor already handles the aggregation. The only thing I'm still curious about is whether or not the java code you suggest could be expressed in camel routes?

Answer (score 0):

[With spring you can pass getBeanNamesForType(Class type)  method an interface class name and recieve a list of all classes that implement them.](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/ListableBeanFactory.html#getBeanNamesForType%28java.lang.Class%29)

Comment: This is not what I'm looking for. If I use this, my application would execute all beans that implement the interface. However I want an explicit specification of which beans the application will call, not an automatic process that calls all beans that implement the interface. I will adjust my question to reflect. Additionally I don't understand yet how to call the resulting beans from a camel route.

Comment: Additionally it seems that the documentation is down at the moment or you used a broken link.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use an observer pattern, like described at Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern

It is designed for passing messages around. Otherwise you also can have a look at [CompleteableFuture](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html) which can send messages (a)synchronously on completion.

Comment: This would be the directions I'd take when I wanted a pure Java solution. But I have Camel and Spring that should be able to take care of this for me in some way.